# Import multiple .CSV's to a macro enabled sheet

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have multiple (5 to be exact) .csv's in a folder, and I would like to make a macro that lets me select the csv files in a folder and import them to a macro enabled blank file. Here is a step by step for what I want to do:

1. Open the main.xlsm
2. Press a macro button in the toolbar that says "Import the CSV's"
3. This will automatically open a browser window and let you find the CSV's somewhere
4. Press Ok and BOOM! just like that all your csv's are exported as xlsm and are separate sheets in the current blank sheet

I tried many different methods of doing this, but I don't think I am on the right path. here is one:

```
Sub convert_to_macro()

    'This first line is crap though. It only lets you export it to a certain place

    ChDir "C:\Users\pal\Documents\CMSe\Lucys Computer"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
      .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
            Exit Sub        
        End If

        something = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "something.xltm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword _
    :="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help given

Comment: Do you need to select the files, or is it all files in this folder?

Comment: Do you want to import or export them? your question says both. What actual problem/error are you having?

Comment: The question was answered, but basically I was looking to import csv's in a xlsm file. So it would **export** the csv to a xlsm and then **import** those files in a single xlsm file. Thanks @brettdj for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this which adds all the csvs to a single file.

```
Sub convert_to_macro()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim strWB

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    'set initial directory to search
    .InitialFileName = "c:\temp"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "csv files", "*.csv"
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
           MsgBox "No selection, exiting"
            Exit Sub
    End If
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(1)

For Each strWB In fd.SelectedItems
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(strWB)
Wb1.Sheets(1).Copy after:=Wb.Sheets(Wb.Sheets.Count)
Wb1.Close False
Next

Wb.Sheets(1).Delete

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```